# Mac Catalyst SwiftUI: Alert showing duplicate buttons

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, alert, mac-catalyst

Does anyone know how to fix this bug? Otherwise I'll create my own alert modal maybe? It seems it's a old bug - at least from macOS 10.15.3, now 10.15.5 and still unresolved. What's funny is that in the first miliseconds after pushing to view it renders correctly - showing only 2 buttons, and then it breaks.
[Alert with multiple buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKH1u.png)

```swift
fileprivate func foo() -> Alert {
        return Alert(title: Text("Foo"),
                     message: Text("Are you sure you want to ..."),
                     primaryButton: .default(Text("Yes"), action: {
                        self.fooAction()
                     }), secondaryButton: .default(Text("No")))
    }
```

and called :

```swift
.alert(isPresented: $isShowingFoo, content:{
            foo()
        })
```

Comment: Show us the code where you’re adding the buttons

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Here ya go!

Comment: Are you getting multiple set actions on isShowingFoo during the presentation. I.e does it need a debounce?

Comment: @WarrenBurton i have only one button with action 
```
actionButton({
                    self. isShowingFoo.toggle()
                }
```
so it's not this kind of a problem. And it works perfectly on iOS side, only macOS has this fault, catalyst fault I suppose. Also when i click on this button many times in a row it may end up crashing with bad instruction :(

Comment: It's a SwiftUI bug. Mac Catalyst alerts present properly with UIKit, but not with SwiftUI.

Comment: @woneill1701 yup, i know, i thought maybe there's some clever hack for it, but for now i've simply created my own popup and it does it's job, but now for example i have to implement touchbar controllers by myself - not that it is **that** useful hahah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember having the same problem in the past, but now it shows the expected buttons. I'm using Xcode 11.5 for a mac catalyst app, targeting ios 13.5 and mac 10.15. Note this is not a macos app.

I have the following test that shows the expected buttons. But I noticed that if I click on a button many times the app crashes after a while.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var isShowingFoo = false

var body: some View {
VStack  {
    Button(action: {
        self.isShowingFoo.toggle()
    }) {
        Text("Press to show alert")
    }
}.alert(isPresented: $isShowingFoo) {
    foo()
}
}

fileprivate func foo() -> Alert {
return Alert(title: Text("Foo"),
             message: Text("Are you sure you want to ..."),
             primaryButton: .default(Text("Yes"), action: {
                self.fooAction()
             }), secondaryButton: .default(Text("No")))
}

func fooAction() {
print("---> Yes fooAction")
}
}
```

I also tried with

```
secondaryButton: .default(Text("no"), action: {})
```

Comment: thanks, but my code is the same when simplified to temporary foo's and still it crashes. For now i've created my own popup, and actually i like it

Comment: ok fair enough. However I'd like to know, does my code crash on your system?

Comment: So, whats funny is that on a empty new project it doesnt, but when i use it in my existing project it has this wrong behavior, also the same as i've got - when clicking on button too many times it crashes the app

Comment: The reader cleared tagged it for MacOS.  Your code doesn't fix the issue.  It's a bug in MacOS especially if you're using NavigationView.  I get duplicate buttons in my alert with this code--->.alert(isPresented: $jsonData.didFail, content: {
          Alert(title: Text("Network Error"),
                message: Text(jsonData.errorMessage),
                dismissButton: .default (Text("OK")))
      })

Answer (score 0):

```
.alert(isPresented: $jsonData.didFail, content: {
          Alert(title: Text("Network Error"),
                message: Text(jsonData.errorMessage),
                dismissButton: .default (Text("OK")))
      })
```

Put that code at the closing block of a container like HStack or VStack.  The didFail variable MUST be a STATE variable or BINDING.  Remember when you hook it to an ALERT the Alert View WILL TOGGLE IT.  So don't use that anywhere else in your logic except for showing the Alert.

Using the code above I STILL get duplicate buttons from inside a NavigationView on MacOS 10.15.6 but it is working on iPhone and iPadOS as expected.

Comment: Thanks, but my code was working on iOS and iPadOS without any problem, unlike macOS :) That's why i've implemented my own alert view and i'm pretty happy with it, considering that it looks almost like the one from big sur, before they've showed big sur hahah

Comment: I just tested this on BigSur Beta build (20A53231) and this bug is still there... ugh... only shows up on MacOs.  Annoying.